# FrameLayout inside of ScrollView

Tags: android, layout

I'm new to android development and I have the following problem.
I need to use `FrameLayout` inside of `ScrollView` for making it scrollable. I wrote this

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:background="#ff0000">
    </FrameLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

But this doesn't work. I tried in `RelativeLayout` and it worked, but I need to use for `FrameLayout`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried many variants for solving this problem, including answers here, but no one was helpful. `ScrollView` always wraps `FrameLayout`, but everything is normal with `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`...

I have found one solution for this - to set minimum height of `FrameLayout`. You can set dynamically minimum height by `setMinimumHeight()` method.

Answer (score 24):

**android:fillViewport="true"** solves this issue.

android:fillViewport, Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport.

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, Fixed my problem! The FrameLayout was getting adjusted automatically all the time.

Answer (score 3):

To get FrameLayout inside ScrollView, do this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutHeader1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1440dp"
             >
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your xml sample is quite good, the only thing I can see is :  if the ScrollLayout parent is bigger than 500dp it won't scroll.

Indeed, the scroll is used only if the content is bigger than the scrollview.

here, you set your content height to 500dip and you scrollview to 'match_parent'
if the parent of this scrollView take the whole screen, on a 800dip height screen (for example)

=> the scroll is simply not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting layout_height to "wrap_content" in your FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000">
```

It will scroll when the FrameLayout will be higher than the screen border. Or if you want the fixed height of scrollable area, set height to 500dp on ScrollView. It depends what you want, but don't ever set the fixed height on a ScrollView child. The ScrollView child's height should always be wrap_content.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000">
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```