# Android FrameLayouts side by side with independent internal scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, scrollview

I'm trying to set up a tablet layout with a list on the left, and a detail pane on the right. When a list item is clicked, the detail pane is populated with a series of cardsthat are longer than the list on the left. I would like the detail pane, and the list (recycler view) to scroll independently of one and other, but I can't fathom how to do so.

Here's my main_content.axml - the recyclerview is loaded into the framelayout listcontainer, and the details are placed into the detailscontainer (the textview is removed before this happens) - but both frames still scroll 'as one' - the entire app scrolls, the frames don't scroll separately.

As an aside, main_content.xml is wrapped inside a nestedscrollview, so that I can use the collapsing toolbar - you can see the main.xml here: http://pastebin.com/raw/PGsVuAp6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/listcontainer"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="450dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >
      </FrameLayout>
  </ScrollView>

  <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

  <ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2">
    <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/detailscontainer"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/nodetails"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="No inspection selected."/>

    </FrameLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit, for clarity, here's what's loaded into the list frame: http://pastebin.com/raw/1Wm8Tntf ----- and here's what's loaded into the detail pane: http://pastebin.com/raw/FetE8JP1

Edit 2: Here's a picture showing how the two frames, list and detail, should scroll, independently of one and other, i.e when you scroll the detail, the list should not move, and when you scroll the list, the detial should not move:

[image]

Comment: Hi can you just add an image with colors will be easy to understand

Comment: @Charuක - I've added it in at the bottom, hope it makes things easier :D

Comment: what about my suggestion?

Comment: I replied to your answer, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `FrameLayout` in the child of `ScrollView` use a `LinearLayout`and it will work!  or try`android:fillViewport="true"` in `ScrollView`

[image]

example xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/listcontainer"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="#897"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="#127"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="#908"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"></LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/listcontainerTwo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="#897"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="#127"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="#908"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"></LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

FrameLayout is just a container and problematic most of the time with ScrollView scenarios if you use `LinearLayout` anyway it scrolls I've tested that. You can find smiler question > [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162386/framelayout-inside-of-scrollview)

Comment: This didn't work, both scrollview scrolled together, like it wasn't registering that the section was scrollable :(

Comment: Could it be because the whole of main_content.axml is warpped in a nested scrollview? See here: http://pastebin.com/raw/PGsVuAp6

Comment: @Joe Brailsford first can you check my out put and tell  me is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @Joe Brailsford thats the layout here in my answer well mm let me have a look on your main_content then

Comment: Thanks, like I say, main_content.axml is included inside a nested scrollview that's in main.axml, you can see this in the pastebin above :)

Comment: @Joe Brailsford  yes thats the reason

Comment: If you make that NestedScrollView another LinearLayout and make that height wrap it will work my questions is whats your requirement if it satisfy your requirement it will let that two views to scroll as two.Having a Scroll View inside another another Scroll View is not a good practice.

Comment: you have a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` **@+id/nest_scrollview** change that to a LinearLayout