# Scrollview getting blocked by linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have a design like this :
XMLFile1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/option_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ScrollView
    android:name="question_paper_scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

XMLFile2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <include layout=XMLFile1.xml>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:weightSum="4"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I have set the `android:fillViewport="true"` in `ScrollView` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36081203/7103753) and also set the `minimumHeight()` of the `FrameLayout` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15587109/7103753). `FrameLayout` holds the quiz questions and they need to be scrollable and the `LinearLayout` consists of set of buttons like next, previous and clear. I learnt from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689455/7103753) `LinearLayout` can hide the `ScrollView` but I can see the ScrollBar. What is the correct way to achieve : Scrollable questions with given design?
PS: I am constrained to use `LinearLayout` because I want set of buttons at the bottom of the screen and to use `FrameLayout` because I am loading the quiz questions dynamically from the database.

**SOLUTION: COMBINATION OF BOTH THE ANSWERS. USE wrap_content in all the layouts and user layout_below attribute in linear layout**

Comment: Show the attributes of your layouts.

Comment: @Dabiuteef added attributes

Comment: I guess this might work: changing the android:layout_height of the LinearLayout to wrap_content, and add android:layout_above="<your_linearlayout_id>" to the include tag.

Comment: set height to wrap_content in both xml files

Comment: Do I have to it only for outermost tags or for all the tags? For the all the tags it does not help because the LineaarLayout holds buttons that function somewhat like bottom tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call `bringToFront()` for ScrollView If it doesn't block the views.
Or adjust `android:height` of views. 
you also set ScrollView to `android:layout_below="@id/includeView"`

Comment: My frame layout gets completely hidden when I do that

Comment: So as I said you should change height of view and set layout_below

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in both xml file take all layout and view's height wrap_content instead of fill_parent or match_parent.

Comment: LinearLayout is for the buttons that act something like bottom tabs. On click next I load a new question into the frame. When I make LinearLayout's height to wrap_content all  the buttons go up.Also the scrollview works only till the buttons and does not go beyond to display  the text below the buttons

Comment: Which orientation do you give to the linear layout?

Comment: Horizantal orientation. If I changed that to vertical then the buttons are stacked one above others. I used linear layout for bottom tabs buttons following this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944692/android-tabs-in-bottom-of-screen

Comment: In xmlfile2 give some fixed height of linear layout and give android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and remove  android:gravity="center|bottom"

Comment: Sorry but by doing that all the buttons go top of the screen